# Remove Warning this expression should have type unit in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Why am I getting Warning this expression should have type unit with this code? although it does what it should do.

```
let matchInf42 list =
        let a = ref 0 in
        let lstLength = List.length list in
        let rec matchInf4242 list = 
        match list with
        |[]->[]
        |m::body->
        begin
        if (m < 42) then a := !a + 1;
        matchInf4242 body
        end
        in matchInf4242 list;
        if(!a = lstLength) then -1 else 0
```

**Warning**:

```
ocamlopt match.ml -o m
File "match.ml", line 14, characters 7-24:
14 |     in matchInf4242 list;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: The error you obtain is a typical type error (mostly)

"Mostly" because, admittedly, it is not an "error" but a mere "warning" here, yet it appears this kind of warning ([Warning 10: non-unit-statement](https://ocaml.org/manual/comp.html#s:comp-options)) is always worth being addressed (i.e., avoided).

It is actually an instance of the following pattern:

```ml
42; print_string "…" ;;

(* or more generally *)
any_value_not_having_type_unit; any_value_having_type_unit ;;

(* which would raise *)
> Characters 0-2:
>   42; print_string "…";;
>   ^^
> Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
> …- : unit = ()
```

#### Further details

Just to recall, `unit` is a singleton type (which only has the value `()`) and is typically chosen to assign a return type to functions that "return no specific value" but produce some side-effect.

Actually, the sequence operator is "a bit more general / more flexible" as what we might expect:

```
# let semicolon i j = i; j ;;
val semicolon : 'a -> 'b -> 'b = <fun>
```

That is to say, it's **not** `semicolon : unit -> 'b -> 'b`, and thereby the message we got for the code `i; j` when `i` does not have the type `unit`, is a mere warning, not a type error.

#### Fixes/workarounds

Two strategies to avoid this warning:

1. Either ignore it by relying on the `ignore` function

   ```ml
   # ignore;;
   - : 'a -> unit = <fun>
   # ignore 42; print_string "…";;
   …- : unit = ()
   ```
2. Or change/fix the way you compute the left-hand side of the sequence (so its type is `unit`).

   In the particular case of your question example, it would suffice to write this (the only change being indicated with a symbol `§`):

   ```ml
   let matchInf42 list =
        let a = ref 0 in
        let lstLength = List.length list in
        let rec matchInf4242 list = 
        match list with
        |[] -> () (*←§*)
        |m::body->
        begin
        if (m < 42) then a := !a + 1;
        matchInf4242 body
        end
        in matchInf4242 list;
        if(!a = lstLength) then -1 else 0
   ```

### Extra remark

Finally for completeness (even though it was not explicitly part of your question), note that the example function you considered could also be implemented in a more "functional" style (without references nor sequences, avoiding also the need for calling the `List.length` function beforehand):

```ml
let matchInf42 l =
  if List.for_all (fun m -> m < 42) l
  then -1 else 0

(* or *)

let matchInf42 l =
  if List.fold_left (fun r e -> r && e < 42) true l
  then -1 else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
`matchInf4242 list`
to either
`ignore (matchInf4242 list)`
or
`matchInf4242 list in ()`.

This makes the statement return `()` (i.e. a unit), which is what ocaml expects.